# Multiple OR Clauses in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

my code is like this: any ideas about avoiding so many or statements?
(sql server)

```
 SELECT ID, COUNT(*) AS UNIQUE_USERS 
FROM 
    (SELECT Address, ID 
        FROM Table
        WHERE 
        (DateSent between '2012-12-21 00:00:00' and '2012-12-21 23:59:59' or
        DateSent between '2012-12-27 00:00:00' and '2012-12-27 23:59:59' or
        DateSent between '2013-01-03 00:00:00' and '2013-01-03 23:59:59' or
            DateSent between '2013-02-27 00:00:00' and '2013-02-27 23:59:59' or
        DateSent between '2013-03-01 00:00:00' and '2013-03-01 23:59:59' or
        DateSent between '2013-03-07 00:00:00' and '2013-03-08 23:59:59' or 
        DateSent between '2013-03-22 00:00:00' and '2013-03-22 23:59:59' 
)AND
        GROUP BY Address, ID
    ) AS USERS
GROUP BY USERS.ID
```

Thanks in advance

*nionios*

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Why do you want to reduce the number of ORs?

Comment: Because this results in ugly SQL, difficult to maintain or optimize?

Comment: Where do the date values come from? The client, another query?

Comment: I am using SQL server 2005
Because this results in ugly SQL,as  Panagiotis Kanavos said, and i like to optimize it
The client gives date value and in .txt form

Comment: @nionios: In that case you should find a way (SSIS) to import dates from .txt to a table and then JOIN on that table.

Comment: So you don't care about anything that happened during the last minute of each of those days? It's almost always better, when dealing with a continuum like time, to use semi-open intervals - e.g. `DateSent >= '20121221' and DateSent < '20121222'`

Comment: @ Nenad Zivkovic: because i am a sql begginer i thought i could be an other way to solve it without creating temp or real tables
@ Damien_The_Unbeliever: Why the whole last minute?

Comment: nionios - because a value like `2012-12-21T23:59:59.537` won't match your current filter for the 21st.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: these are millisecs i think and yes i don't care about anything that happened during them

Comment: @nionios - that's certainly unusual - you care about everything that happened between the start of a day and up until 23:59:59, but you don't care about what happens during that final minute?

Answer (score 2):

You could do it as by casting to a date and using `in`:

```
  SELECT ID, COUNT(distinct address)
  FROM Table
  WHERE cast(datesent as date) in ('2012-12-21', '2012-12-27', '2013-01-03',
                                   '2013-02-27', '2013-03-01', '2013-03-07',
                                   '2013-03-22'
                                  ) and . . .
  GROUP BY ID
```

I also modified the query to use `count(distinct)` instead of a subquery.  The results should be the same, assuming that `address` is never `NULL`.  If it can be `NULL` and you want to count that, then you can do:

```
  SELECT ID, COUNT(distinct address) +
             max(case when address is null then 1 else 0 end)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `DATEPART` function gives you an integer that represents the date part of your column without the time-of-day part. Maybe you could compare on that.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx#GetDateandTimeParts

Comment: That won't reduce the OR statements

Comment: Literally true, but it will make the components of the `OR` statements about half as bulky.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running SQL Server 2008 or newer where datatype `DATE` exists, you can change to:

```
WHERE CAST(DateSent AS DATE) IN ('2012-12-21','2012-12-27','2013-01-03','2013-02-27','2013-03-07','2013-03-22)
```

If on SQL Server 2005 (as it turns out), you can achieve the same with:

```
WHERE DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, DateSent)) IN 
     ('2012-12-21','2012-12-27','2013-01-03','2013-02-27','2013-03-07','2013-03-22)
```

Answer (score 0):

The canonical SQL solution is to use a table containing the dates you want to test against and do an inner join between your table and the table of dates and return only the source rows that have a match in the dates table.

There various ways you can create the dates table:

- You can create a real table in the database with the values you want. Usefull if you need to check against the same set of dates.
- You can create a temporary table in your statement and fill it with the values you need. Only practical if you have a few date values to check.
- You can pass the dates table as a table-valued parameter to your query. Only available in SQL Server 2008 and later. Usefull if the list of dates is generated by a client application

Gordon's solution is better if you have a small number of dates and is also much simpler to code.

**EDIT**
Since the dates come from a text file, you should import the file in a table using either SSIS or the [BULK INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) T-SQL command and join the tables.

BULK INSERT is preferable because you can combine both the BULK INSERT and your query statements in the same batch. BULK INSERT requires that the file is a simple delimited file and the text data can be converted to the target column's type without explicit conversions. BULK INSERT can handle some conversions but it may become too cumbersome for simple jobs.

SSIS allows great flexibility while importing data but it's YetAnotherExternalTool to use.

Comment: unfortunately dates are not few and change every time

Comment: Where do the dates come from? The client, another query or view, user data?

Answer (score 0):

SQL2005 or after

```
WITH Dates AS 
(
    SELECT '2012-12-21' AS DateToCheck
    UNION SELECT '2012-12-27'
    UNION SELECT '2013-01-03'
    UNION SELECT '2013-02-27'
    UNION SELECT '2013-03-01'
    UNION SELECT '2013-03-07'
    UNION SELECT '2013-03-22'

)
SELECT ID, COUNT(*) AS UNIQUE_USERS
FROM dbo.Table
INNER JOIN  Dates ON CONVERT(Date, DateSent) = DateToCheck
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: Why do this CTE and UNIONS when you can just do an IN (...)

Answer (score 0):

If you cast the timestamp to date, and since your ranges are full days, logically you can code it as a single `IN (...)`:

```
...
SELECT Address, ID 
    FROM Table
    WHERE CAST (DateSent AS DATE) IN ('2012-12-21', '2012-12-27', '2013-01-03', '2013-02-27', '2013-03-01', '2013-03-07', '2013-03-22') 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have large table you could create an indexed view with ID and Date.

```
CREATE VIEW VIEW_TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS

SELECT ID, CONVERT(DATE, DATESENT) DateSent
FROM TABLE

GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ixDateView
ON [VIEW_Table] (DateSent)
```

After

```
 SELECT ID, COUNT(distinct address)
  FROM View_Table WITH (NOEXPAND)
  WHERE DateSent in (
     '2012-12-21', 
     '2012-12-27', 
     '2013-01-03',
     ...)
  GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #dates (DateFrom datetime, DateTo datetime)
insert into #dates (DateFrom, DateTo) values
    ('2012-12-21 00:00:00', '2012-12-21 23:59:59')
    , ('2012-12-27 00:00:00', '2012-12-27 23:59:59')
    etc...


SELECT ID, COUNT(*) AS UNIQUE_USERS 
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT Address, ID
        FROM [Table]
            join #dates on [Table].DateSent between #dates.DateFrom and #dates.DateTo
    ) AS USERS
GROUP BY USERS.ID
```